# Load one UI on top of another

Tags: c++, event-handling, qml, blackberry-10

I am Developing a BB10 app.

I have one QML file which contains a Login Button.

When user clicks on the Login Button another QML file containing the username and password textboxes and two buttons submit and cancel should be loaded.

On clicking cancel button user to should go back to initial QML containing Login Button.

How can I accomplish such a scenario using C++

Comment: No idea. We haven't seen what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function on clicking the login button to load the next qml file.

```
ApplicationUI::ApplicationUI(bb::cascades::Application *app) :
    QObject(app) {
QmlDocument *loginQml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///Login.qml").parent(
        this);
loginQml->setContextProperty("myApp", this);
rootLogin = loginQml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
rootLogin->setParent(this);

QmlDocument *secondPage = QmlDocument::create("asset:///SecondPage.qml").parent(
        this);
secondPage->setContextProperty("myApp", this);
rootSecond = secondPage->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
rootSecond->setParent(this);

callFirstQml();
}
void ApplicationUI::callFirstQml() {
Application::instance()->setScene(0);
Application::instance()->setScene(rootLogin);
}

void ApplicationUI::callSecondQml() {
Application::instance()->setScene(0);
Application::instance()->setScene(rootSecond);
}
```

Guess this will work for you. Make sure to write the function names as QINVOKABLE in the header file. Also the rootLogin and rootSecond should be written in the header file too, as this,

```
private:
bb::cascades::TabbedPane *rootLogin;
bb::cascades::TabbedPane *rootSecond;
```